# How do I determine the List<Object>'s object?

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking to create a generic method that receives a List. I need to determine what the object is within the list so that I can then do the necessary work according to the object that is being passed in within the list. How can I determine the kind of object that the List contains?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use a more specific type (e.g. List<MyType>, List<string>, etc.)

Comment: I have several lists of different, but similar objects that I will need to use this method for.

Comment: If the objects are similar, then why not create an interface for them? There should be some strong argument why you want to determine the exact type since this is usually not good practice. Otherwise, the "is" keyword should help your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you have the `is` keyword,  which can compare objects

```
if(myObject is MyClass)
    doStuff();
```

you also have

```
typeof(myObject);
```

and as L.B. said, you have

```
obj.GetType() too
```

Answer (score 1):

given

```
List<T> objects;
```

you can get the type like this

```
var objType = typeof(T);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the object type is not one of the generic parameters of your method then you can use the [Type.GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method that returns the types of the parameters of a generic type (in your case List).

Else if the object type is one of the generic parameters of your method then use Travis J's answer.